# Calculate no of days between two dates in java

Tags: java, date, datetime

I need to calculate number of days between two dates and I am using below code. problem is it is returning me 2 but actually it should return 3 because difference between 30 june 2016 to 27 june is 3. can you please help where it should include current date as well in difference?

```
public static long getNoOfDaysBtwnDates(String expiryDate) {
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date expDate = null;
    long diff = 0;
    long noOfDays = 0;
    try {

        expDate = formatter.parse(expiryDate);
        //logger.info("Expiry Date is " + expDate);
       // logger.info(formatter.format(expDate));

        Date createdDate = new Date();
        diff = expDate.getTime() - createdDate.getTime();
        noOfDays = TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        long a = TimeUnit.DAYS.toDays(noOfDays);
       // logger.info("No of Day after difference are - " + TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(noOfDays);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return noOfDays;
}
```

expiry date is 2016-06-30 and current date is 2016-06-27

Comment: @AngryJS Checkout my answer!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reason is, you are not subtracting two dates with same time format.

Use Calendar class to change the time as 00:00:00 for both date and you will get exact difference in days.

```
Date createdDate = new Date();
Calendar time  = Calendar.getInstance();
time.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
time.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
time.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
time.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
createdDate = time.getTime();
```

More explaination in Jim Garrison' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38047022/3556394)

Comment: Just did that and deployed :).

Answer (score 5):

Why not use `LocalDate`?

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import static java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.DAYS;

long diffInDays(LocalDate a, LocalDate b) {
  return DAYS.between(a, b);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that

```
Date createdDate = new Date();
```

sets `createdDate` to the *current instant*, that is, it includes the current time as well as the date.  When you parse a string using the given format, the time is initialized to `00:00:00`.

Let's say you ran this at exactly 18:00 local time, you end up with

```
createdDate = 2016-06-27 18:00:00.000
expDate     = 2016-06-30 00:00:00.000
```

The difference is 2 days 6 hours, not 3 days.

You should be using the newer `java.time.*` classes from Java 8.  There is a class `LocalDate` that represents dates without time-of-day.  It includes methods for parsing using a format, and `LocalDate.now()` to get the current date, as well as methods for calculating intervals between `LocalDate` instances.

Comment: Then how can I fix it? so that if I enter expiry as 30 June, it should give number of days as 3 only i.e. which actually calculates difference between dates not time.

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score -1):

Using the `Calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)` as pointed out by python:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date expDate = null;
String expiryDate ="2016-06-30";
int diff = 0;
try {
    expDate = formatter.parse(expiryDate);
    //logger.info("Expiry Date is " + expDate);
    // logger.info(formatter.format(expDate));
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int today = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    cal.setTime(expDate);
    diff = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)- today;

} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println(diff);
```

Comment: Nice and elegant solution but getDay method is deprecated since jdk6. Deprecated. As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by Calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH).

Comment: looks fine now, cal.setTime(expDate) , this was cool!

Comment: Will not work if both dates to be compared with are in different months.

Comment: Yes, doesnt work if dates are of different month and doesnt even meet basic need!